# How to use PHP API to add multiple records in 1 call?

Tags: php

I have made a simple PHP API to insert record in the database using the POST method as shown below:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-requested-with');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');
header("Content-Type: application/json"); // tell client that we are sending json data


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$dxname  =$_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO crudtable(firstname, lastname, email,favjob)
VALUES ('".$dxname."', 'Doe', 'john@example.com','coder')";

if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
{ echo json_encode("New record created successfully");
   // echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo json_encode("Some error");
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I am checking my api using Chrome Postman, you can see the result of Postman in the below image:

[image]

I am passing the field to be stored like this `name: Tim`

I want to save multiple records / multiple names in 1 call. How can I do so and check it using Postman?

Comment: Well first decide how you are going to send many names to your php script. Then code the script to accept and process them

Comment: If you have to use URL-encoded data, change the names on your fields to `firstname[]`, `lastname[]`, `email[]`, `favjob[]`.  PHP converts these parameters to an array which you can iterate over.

Comment: you have to use loop

Comment: can you update the update code and guide me how do i pass values using postman

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO crudtable
    (firstname, lastname, email,favjob)
VALUES
    (1,2,3,4),
    (5,6,7,8),
    (9,10,11,12);
```

However, it is depend how you gonna pass multiple variables into the server side with PHP?

The number of records you would like to insert is known or unknown?
if you gonna have an array of variables you better iterate on the array and insert each one.

Anyway, I would strongly recommend to use prepared statements in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

It is safer, and easier in my opinion to implement.

Comment: can you update my code and let me know how can i test using php , u can just insert name, rest of the fields, no need to insert

Comment: Can you tell me how you gonna accept multiple names? Are you going to send each one separately or array of all of the names? That way I would be able to assist you better.

Comment: i can follow any approach, i am open to that. You can guide me the best way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Pass name paranter in array line present in image below

In the php script

get the name parameter in a array variable.

[image]

Below is the code how to process the multiple names coming from the request.

```
$names= $_POST['name'];

$valuesToInsert= array();

foreach($names as $nm)
{
  $valuesToInsert[] = "('".$nm."', 'Doe', 'john@example.com','coder')";
}

if(!empty($valuesToInsert))
{
  $stringValues = implode(", ", $valuesToInsert);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO crudtable(firstname, lastname, email,favjob)
  VALUES $stringValues";

  if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
  { echo json_encode("New record created successfully");
     // echo "New record created successfully";
  } else {
      echo json_encode("Some error");
     // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }

}
```